# How to maintain constant line length around a rotating joint

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics

I'm working on a design for a robotic leg that uses strings as "tendons" for extending and retracting the leg.  This is as much a geometry problem as it is a mechanical engineering problem.  Refer to the two simplified images below.  Points A1 and B1 are where the lines are attached to the arms of a stepper motor centered at C.  An axle runs through a joint at point D.  The lines run around the D axle and attach to an outer leg segment at points A2 and B2 that rotates around an axle at point E.  The rotation of the stepper motor thus controls the rotation of the outer leg segment around point E.

A separate mechanism (not shown) rotates the leg segment DE around the axle at point D.  Between retraction and extension, the angle CDE can vary from 45 degrees to about 150 degrees.  The problem is that when this leg segment is rotated, the line length from A1 to A2 and B1 to B2 changes because distance that the lines travel around the axle at point D changes.  Compare the retracted and extended images.  In the retracted position, the lines must be longer because they have to go around more of the surface of the axle at D.  This results in the lines being either too tight in the retracted position or too loose in the extended position.  The effect can be minimized by reducing the diameter of the axle at D, but its size is limited by other design constraints.

The question is whether the geometry around the axle at point D can be modified such that the line lengths can remain constant as the joint is rotated.  My best guess is that this can be accomplished with a partial corkscrew shape around the axle and affixed to the DE segment such that as the leg is extended, it takes up the slack in the lines.  I'm hoping that there are other geometric configurations that I have not considered that are easier to manufacture.  The solution might also be one that minimizes the change in line length rather than completely eliminating it.

[retracted joint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK9dy.png)

[extended joint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnIdL.png)

Comment: You know bicycles have several of these "strings" by which a lever on the handlebar can be used to pull on things such as gear shift mechanisms and brakes, right? Notice how they solve the extension/retraction problem.

Comment: If you cannot use the bicycle-maker's solution, you could consider making the strings just long enough for the extended position, and letting the pulley at D move to allow the leg to retract. Or maybe just mount the pulley in a different place. The surfaces bearing the "strings" and the surfaces bearing the leg joint must be different surfaces anyway, so I see no reason to insist they must all be on one cylinder.

Comment: Can you have A1 and B1 attached to concentric circles at C?

Comment: The handlebar lever solution is something I have considered but was trying to avoid.  Such a mechanism uses a spring somewhere in the mechanism to take up the slack.  I may yet resort to that if other solutions don't perform to my liking, but finding and installing a spring with the proper spring constant, dimensions, and attachment points has been a challenge.

Comment: Letting the pulley at D move is an intriguing idea, but I'm not sure what mechanism I could devise to move it in the proper direction and, yet again, would likely require a spring of the proper spring constant and dimensions (I am also working with very limited space).  Mounting the pulley in a different place would have to be done in such a way that the DE segment rotation offsets the change in the length of string contacting the pulley during rotation.  That's something I'd have to think about.

Comment: Chrystomath, I'm not quite sure what you mean about A1 and B1.  If the new circles are still centered around point C, I don't see how it changes the outcome.  Ignoring B1 for the moment, The line A1 to D to A2 still changes in length around the axle at D.

Comment: I found a stepper motor that has more torque, and I was also able to reduce the axle diameter.  I think this has reduced the slack well enough to abandon other solutions.  Thanks for the feedback anyway.